# Canon printer mp220 driver problem

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have a problem with my canon mp 220 printer. The driver works well only if the page is full written. But if it's... let'say 4 or 5 rows written, it prints the 4 or 5 rows and after that it says the printing it's finished but the paper it's inside of the printer, and the printer it's blocked.

What's goining on? Is it a driver problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you work your way through the following posts, you will see how I resolved the same issue for my canon MP240, (running 64 bit ubuntu 12.04).  My Canon printer is working very nicely now.  I suggest you look first at my original post describing the issue here...

https://www.ultimateeditionoz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=142&t=4453

Then go to the solution, I suggest you start at the bottom of this rather long post and work your way back

https://www.ultimateeditionoz.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=3567&p=33450#p33450

It should all be self explanatory.  Good Luck.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.